# Hilbert series of exterior algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, commutative-algebra, graded-modules

Let the exterior polynomial algebra $A=\Lambda_K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ have grading $\deg x_i=d_i$. Is there some nice formula for the Hilbert-Poincare series $HP_A=\sum_k\dim_K \!A_k\,t^k\in\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ of this algebra?

If $d_1\!=\!\ldots\!=\!d_n\!=\!d$, then $HP_A=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}t^{dk}=(1+t^d)^n$. But I have trouble with the general case.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized that $\Lambda[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cong\Lambda(K^n)\cong\Lambda(\bigoplus_{i=1}^nK)\cong \Lambda[x_1]\otimes'\ldots\otimes'\Lambda[x_n]$, hence $HP_A=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+t^{d_i})$. Can anyone confirm this?